# difference between Graph API Explorer access token and App access token

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

What is the difference between Graph API Explorer access token and App access token.

When I try to post with restfb using App access token I am not able to see my post in the page. The same post is visible when it is posted using Graph API Explorer access token.

I am force to use App access token as the Graph API Explorer access token is short validity.

Comment: You should use a page access otken.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best to read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) through the facebook developer documentation,

but as a summary,

- User access tokens are needed any time the app calls an API to read, modify or write a specific person's Facebook data on their behalf.
- App access tokens are needed to modify and read the app settings. It can also be used to publish Open Graph actions.
- Page Access Tokens are similar to user access tokens, except that they provide permission to APIs that read, write or modify the data belonging to a Facebook Page.

You will also find on that page some details on how to make your token "live" longer.